# Microservices: C# WebAPI authorization against external service.(end point)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, webapi

I have a webapi endpoint. I need to use external jwt authorization for the calls.
Basically There are several microservices. When the call hits this particular service which has the webapi controller with the JWT token in the header, need to call the external authorization server endpoint to validate and get the roles and identity in return.

I have already implemented this by extending AuthorizationFilterAttribute. But I am looking at using OWIN. Is there a way I do this via OWIN which intercepts, validates the token when a request hits the controller.

Note: I will just have to unauthorize if the token is invalid.

Adding code :

```
[JwtAuthorizationFilter]
    public class abcController : ApiController
    {
    }


 public class JwtAuthorizationFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            try {
            //Parse and get token from Header
                var requestToken = FetchRequestTokenFromHeader(actionContext);
            //Call(postasync) external enpoint to validate the token and get jwtdetails 
                var validationResponseMessage = JwtValidation(requestToken, actionContext);
            //crate a generic identity and set actioncontext
                ParseValidationResponseMessage(actionContext, validationResponseMessage);

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Logger.Info("Exception on authorization: " + exception.Message);
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: We would like to know what you have done from your side. Would you able to share any snippet.

Comment: added .please check